# Angular scss url(), cant resolve relative path when project is build

Tags: css, angular, url, build, relative-path

i have a folder filled with svg's (path: src/assets/icons).
The css function **url()** is implemented like this:

```
url("/assets/icons/CheckSmall.svg");
```

It finds the svg data, when I run ***ng serve***.
But when I build my Project, it cant find the svg data. Although it exists in the folder *dist/myApp/assets/icons/CheckSmall.svg*

I have read through many forums and discussions and tested a few things (One of many [discussions](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12797#issuecomment-598559534)).

For example i used different pathing "strategies":

```
 1. url("^assets/icons/CheckSmall.svg")
 2. url("~/assets/icons/CheckSmall.svg")
```

For number (1) it seems like it is not a supported feature in Angular, thats why i dont want to use it. And for (2) it copies my Assets and puts them into the folder *dist/myApp*.

Is there a viable(supported or documented) alternative? Or can I somehow adjust the *angular.json*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following syntax:

```css
background-image: url('../../assets/icons/<file-name>')
```

Where the route is relative to the `css` file

If you're setting non-default `baseHref` or `deployUrl` flags as part of the build that can also affect it

Try using that approach in styles.scss or in the relevant component, without the scss variable. The relative path won't be correct when the scss variable is used in different folders

Comment: Does not work for me...
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):

ModuleError: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PROJECTNAME\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\forms\_form-check.scss:58:8: Can't resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap/assets/icons/CheckSmall_currentColor.svg' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PROJECTNAME\src'
    at Object.emitError (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PROJECTNAME\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:562:6) ...

Comment: Its probably from my styling for Bootstrap. Maybe the Screenshot i added helps more.